# Method on class was used outside of a Grails application

Tags: java, grails

Gails 2.4.4 on mac running java 7.0_25

I removed $HOME/.grails
Started in a new directory

- grails create-app foo
- cd foo
- grails
- run-app
- create-domain-class Newtest

added a single String to this class

```
package testapp

class Newtest {

String TestString

def index() {}

static constraints = {}
}
```

Then I added this to BootStrap

```
class BootStrap {

def init = { servletContext ->

    new Newtest(TestString: "testme").save()

}
def destroy = {
 }
}
```

**stop-app

clean

run-app**

```
| Running Grails application
| Error 2014-12-16 16:20:34,822 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoaderListener  - Error initializing the application: Method on class [testapp.Newtest] was used outside of a Grails application. If running in the context of a test using the mocking API or bootstrap Grails correctly.
Message: Method on class [testapp.Newtest] was used outside of a Grails application. If running in the context of a test using the mocking API or bootstrap Grails correctly.
```

Everything is default and I used examples from google to make sure I had it all setup correctly.

Can someone tell me what is wrong or if this is a bug of some sort ?

Comment: I wonder if all the things are by default, There are few issues , where you have put "Newtest" domain class?? Is this in grails-app/domian artifact , and I think `def index() {}` should not be in domain class and name of variables 'String TestString' should be 'String testString'i.e in camel case

Comment: You have just copy paste your project. Please create correct package for your domain class. It looks like it assume "testapp" as directory not package.